# Дополнить интерфейс Unity, Custom Inspector

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Появилось требование к дополнению интерфейса самого unity, и хотелось бы узнать, это вообще возможно или нет.

Подробнее:
Есть проект который использует движок для создания схем помещений(их дизайна и тп), т.е. воссоздают магазины, квартиры и тп. Дизайнерам хотелось бы иметь какие-то функции или информацию(площадь помещения, тип объекта(при наведении), сколько объектов всего на сцене и т.п), которые отсутствуют в дефолтной версии. Возможно ли дописать это скриптами или как аддон?

Например:
При наведении на объект, в редакторе, я могу видеть его Transform, Mesh Render и т.п, но хотел бы еще увидеть, например, Options, где было бы иия объекта, id и тп. Всем спасибо)

Comment: Что значит "при наведении на объект"? Если уж мы говорим про редактор, вы, видимо, имели в виду при выборе объекта (клик на объекте) в редакторе?

Comment: "Options, где было бы имя объекта, id и тп" - это, я так понимаю, данные из вашего кастомного скрипта? В общем, в юнити в плане изменения интерфейса возможно все, даже переопределение отрисовки инспектора уже встроенных компонентов, не говоря уже о кастомных. Но чтобы понять, что вам именно нужно, дополните вопрос.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Да, все о чем я говорю, о редакторе. Нужно чтобы в редакторе, например, при выборе объекта, показывались расстояния до ближайших объектов. Пример проще. Хочу чтобы у каждого объекта выводилась его длина ширина высота(в метрах).

Comment: Про длину, ширину и высоту сказать довольно трудно - тут либо нужно с Bounding Box`ом меши работать, либо использовать сторонний плагин, но это уже к вопросу не относится. С примером "показывались расстояния до ближайших объектов" распишу.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker дело не в вычислении, а в выводе. Тут сложность в чем, ребята с редактором работают, скажем, не программисты. И хотелось бы иметь простой способ, чтобы скрипт действовал на все объекты на сцене ну или что-то подобное.

Comment: А подобный вывод в каком виде лучше, как отдельный компонент или отдельное окно? По аналогии сможете одно через другое написать, но что предпочтительнее для примера?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker в идеале, при выборе объекта в меню инспектора(где transform и тп) показывать эту информацию. Расстояния показывать прям на сцене в редакторе(если возможно). Если есть еще какие-то варианты, как делают обычно, я бы о них узнал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный пример иллюстрирует решение конкретной задачи - кастомный инспектор для дебаг-компонента, предназначенного для показа расстояния от выделенного объекта до окружающих его объектов. По аналогии можно решить любую другую задачу, но, подчеркиваю, я не использовал в данном примере какие-то сложные концепты, например, откат к предыдущей "версии" значений компонента через ctrl+z, это и прочие полезные вещи - тема отдельного вопроса.

Итак, приступим:

**Сама "логика" дебага**, который будет отрисовывать отрезок от выделенного объекта ко всем другим на основе заданного радиуса. Лично я не знаю какого-то рационального способа сделать это *без* использования физики, так что ее я и использую. Вроде все достаточно просто, если возникнут вопросы - дополню.

```
public class DebugBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    public float surroundingsCheckRadius = 10f;
    public bool drawDistanceToNearestObjects = false;
    public bool drawDistanceLabel = false;
    public Color debugInfoColor = Color.red;

    public void DisplayDistanceToSurroundings() {
        Gizmos.color = debugInfoColor;
        foreach (var col in Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, surroundingsCheckRadius)) {
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, col.transform.position);

            if (drawDistanceLabel) {
                DrawColoredLabel(col.transform.position, Vector3.Distance(transform.position, col.transform.position).ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected() {
        if (drawDistanceToNearestObjects) {
            DisplayDistanceToSurroundings();
        }
    }

    private void DrawColoredLabel(Vector3 pos, string text) {
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        style.normal.textColor = debugInfoColor;
        Handles.Label(pos, text, style);
    }
}
```

**Кастомный инспектор для нашего компонента.** Из, возможно, новых вещей, стоит отметить атрибуты `CustomEditor`/`MenuItem`. Первый говорит Unity, для какого компонента нужно использовать этот GUI, второй добавляет в тулбар Unity новые варианты, путь к которым в параметре атрибута и прописывается, и вызывает данную функцию, в данном случае просто добавляет и удаляет компонент, такой подход для "не программистов" будет удобнее.

Также стоит отметить, что наследуемся мы от Editor и переопределяем `OnInspectorGUI` - тот метод, который и рисует окна инспектора. В нем важно первым делом получить ссылку на сам объект, для которого мы этот GUI и рисуем, а дальше просто используем API для создания, в данном случае, цветового поля, парочки bool`ов и float для радиуса.
    using UnityEditor;

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(DebugBehaviour))]
public class DebugBehaviourEditor : Editor {
    [MenuItem("Tools/Add Personal Debugger")]
    public static void AddDebugBehaviour() {
        foreach(var go in Selection.gameObjects) {
            if (!go.GetComponent<DebugBehaviour>()) {
                go.AddComponent<DebugBehaviour>();
            }
        }
    }

    [MenuItem("Tools/Remove Personal Debugger")]
    public static void RemoveDebugBehaviour() {
        foreach (var go in Selection.gameObjects) {
            DestroyImmediate(go.GetComponent<DebugBehaviour>());
        }
    }

    DebugBehaviour myTarget;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        myTarget = target as DebugBehaviour;

        myTarget.debugInfoColor = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Debug color", myTarget.debugInfoColor);

        myTarget.drawDistanceToNearestObjects = 
            EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft("Draw distances", myTarget.drawDistanceToNearestObjects);

        if (myTarget.drawDistanceToNearestObjects) {
            myTarget.surroundingsCheckRadius =
                EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Distance check radius", myTarget.surroundingsCheckRadius);
            myTarget.drawDistanceLabel =
                EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Draw distance text", myTarget.drawDistanceLabel);
        }
    }
}
```

Разумеется, это самый простой пример, но довольно показательный, как быстро и просто можно написать свой инспектор, дальше - документация и форум, о таких вещах можно вечно говорить, а стэк - далеко не форум :)

Примеры работы:
[image: Вид на кастомный инспектор]
[image: Выделение нескольких объектов]

**Update**

Использование EditorWindow вместо инспектора компоненты.

Принцип работы почти такой же, за исключение создания окна - это нужно делать явно через `GetWindow<EditorWindow>`. Также нужно понимать, что "из коробки" Unity обновляет GUI окна при фокусе (фактически вызывает `EditorWindow.Repaint()`), а нам нужно отслеживать обновление выделения объектов, для чего мы собственноручно помещаем `EditorWindow.Repaint()` в `OnSelectionChange()` - колбек, зависящий как раз от изменения выделения в редакторе.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class DebugBehaviourEditorWindow : EditorWindow {

    [MenuItem("Tools/Debug Behaviour Window")]
    public static void ShowWindow() {
        GetWindow<DebugBehaviourEditorWindow>("Debug Behaviour Window");
    }

    private void OnGUI() {
        if (Selection.gameObjects.Length != 0) {
            foreach (var go in Selection.gameObjects) {
                var reqComp = go.GetComponent<DebugBehaviour>();

                // проверяем, что наш шкаф из выделения действительно шкаф
                // ну и что-то делаем с ним
                if (reqComp) {
                    // на скорую руку (криво) выводим какие-то данные про наш шкаф
                    GUILayout.Label(go.name + " check radius is: " + reqComp.surroundingsCheckRadius.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnSelectionChange() {
        Repaint();
    }
}
```

Данное окно ничем не отличается в встроенных окон Unity - инспектора, ассет стора и т.д. - оно так же хорошо перемещается мышкой и прикрепляется куда угодно в редакторе, а внутренняя реализация безгранична (в разумных пределах).
[image: Пример с окном и отображением данных]

Comment: Просто волшебно, но у меня остался последний вопрос. Можно ли применить один скрипт ко всем объектам на сцене или к каждому придется добавлять его как компонент? Например, есть общая информация, длинна, ширина, которую хотелось бы вывести для ВСЕХ объектов, и добавлять скрипт для каждого, я считаю, не удобно

Comment: Смотря, куда выводить, вы же явно не хотите выводить информацию для всех объектов в компонент какого-то конкретного объекта? Для этого можно создать свое окно - наследоваться от EditorWindow и немного по-другому создавать его и переопределять другие методы.

Comment: предположим есть 5 шкафов, и наводя на любой из них, я хочу видеть его длину ширину высоту в инспекторе, для одного конкретного это не проблема. Но сделать скрипт 1, но чтобы он работал для всех, я не нашел как.

Comment: Внутри создать какой-нибудь массив для вывода информации - это все просто и прописано в доках. А для выборки конкретных объектов можно использовать Selection.gameObjects, который вернет список всех выделенных объектов, из которых мы в этом окне и будет выводить информацию.

Comment: Так в этом и смысл отдельного EditorWindow - оно никак не привязано к конкретному объекту. В общем ладно, сейчас отдельным ответом покажу, как это делается, а то оригинальный ответ и так слишком большой.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, обратите внимание, что это именно отдельное окно, оно никак не привязано к какиму-либо объекту и полностью автономно. Полностью обновляется при обновлении выделения.

Comment: да, это отличное решение, я его позаимствую, но все же хотелось бы для других инструментов иметь возможность создавать скрипт, который бы применялся для всех объектов. сложность окна в том, что его нужно открыть, иногда, для людей со складом ума, отличным от нашего, это большая проблема. Огромное вам спасибо, очень помогли)

Comment: С помощью [MenuItem("")] вы можете вызвать какой-то метод, который будет применять что угодно к массиву объектов из Selection.gameObjects. Вопрос в том, что эту информацию все равно надо куда-то выводить :)