# Inspector для своего типа в Unity Editor

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Я так понимаю в инспекторе Unity не отображаются публичные поля с типом интерфейс?
Например что то типо того

`public IMovable moveController;`

Покопался в зарубежных форумах, там вроде бы говорят что то типо того что нужно писать кастомный редактор, не совсем понял.
На русском такого материала не нашел.
Может кто то знает как решить данную задачу или может альтернативы есть?

Comment: Оригинальный инспектор не отображает не только "интерфейс"`ы, он ни один пользовательский тип не отображает, т.к. не знает, как его отображать. Свой интерфейс для кастомных типов (да и для встроенных тоже) можно переопределить. Без конкретного вопроса я ничего сказать не могу, но вот конкретный пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866267/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81-unity-custom-inspector/866821#866821

Comment: ок, спасибо, буду знать, попробую разобраться)

Comment: Зачем отображать интерфейс в инспекторе, интересно?

Comment: @Pepsi4, отображать реализованные интерфейсы без наследования от MonoBehaviour? В любом случае Unity не очень дружит с пользовательскими типами, так что вопрос достаточно актуальный.

Comment: ну тут дело не в его отображении, а в том чтобы драг н дропом перенести туда компонент

Comment: @phpred, Альтернатива - абстрактный класс)